# How to translate alert message

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

I uploaded a translation package from Magaplaze. 
but alert messages as text in red color in an image below not translated. how to do it?

Magento CE 2.1.9
[image]

Comment: Do you know where this text is coming from? If it is coming from a ko js file you can follow my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems the text you are trying to translate is coming from ko js.
For translating phrases from ko js you should provide  i18n: in front of the value of data-bind attribute.
Something like below;

```
<element data-bind="i18n: something: function() {
    return $t('some string');
}" />
```

**Note:** Please note that the translation for corresponding string should be present  in your language translation csv.

Comment: how to provide i18n: in front of the value of data-bind attribute???

Comment: As mentioned in the code

Comment: in which file I should but this code?

Comment: Do you know the file where the text to be translated is written?

Comment: yes in csv file

Comment: No I meant do you know where the text "this is required field "is coming from?

Comment: no, what is the path of this form?

Comment: form where "this is required field" is coming? please, complete your answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be translated once the translation files are added. There is no any additional efforts required in case you are following the Magento 2 best practices.

Generally we need to add the text in below way to make it translatable by translation files:

```
<?php echo __('The text to be translated'); ?>
```

Comment: @Ahmedabad all the text" this is a required feild" is translated in translation files. where should i put this code?

Comment: Please check step by step explanation at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html

Comment: also check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html :), hope it help!

Comment: @Ahmedabad really not help is there steps to solve this issue?